# RxJava how to observe on mainThread in older versions? I dont have access to AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: android, rx-java, web3-java

Im building a project using web3.

```
web3j.ethGetBalance("0x2910543af39aba0cd09dbb2d50200b3e800a63d2", latestBlock)
            .observable()
            .subscribeOn(rx.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
            //This needs to be on the main thread!
            //But i only have access to rx.schedulers not AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
            .observeOn(rx.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(block -> {
                ethereumTV.setText(block.getBalance() + "");
            }, error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
            });
```

But web3 uses an older version of RxJava and i cant access the mainThread to observe on it (To update text views etc)

Any ideas?

Comment: `compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'`
/* Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also */
/* explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.*/
`compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'`

Comment: this is my problem though -> 'observeOn(rx.Scheduler)' in 'rx.Observable' cannot be applied to '(io.reactivex.Scheduler)'

Comment: if you can't add the `rxandroid` dependency to get `AndroidSchedulers` then you may have to build your own `Scheduler`. The main thread scheduler was just a wrapper around `handler.post(...)` anyway.

Comment: find out what version of rx you do have, and see if there was a corresponding rxandroid version with the same package names

Comment: You need to use `rx.android.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

Comment: Spot on as always EpicPandaForce. Coupled with the 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1' import, rx.android.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() works. Thank you so much dude. Want to add it as an answer so i can give you some marks? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1' // <-- this is needed
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
```

Then you can get

> in 'rx.Observable' cannot be applied to '(io.reactivex.Scheduler)'

In which case do

```
rx.android.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
```

Comment: But technically you could also use the RxJava2Interop library to convert `rx.Observable` into `io.reactivex.Observable`